# Latest objects of every group with Django filter in mysql backend

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have 2 Models:

```
class WLSDomainName(BaseMixin):
    domain_name = models.CharField('Domain Name',max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    site_name = models.CharField('Site Name', max_length=10, choices = SITE_NAME, default='dc',blank=False, null=False)
    delete_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class DomainOverallHealthStatus(BaseMixin):
    domain_name = models.ForeignKey(WLSDomainName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False, related_name="overall_health_status_domain_name") 
    configuredServerCount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    activeServerCount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    overallServiceHealth = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    activeThreadCount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    activeHttpSessionCount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    classification_time = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to find the latest object from DomainOverallHealthStatus model for every object of WLSDomainName.

I have tried:

```
o_health = DomainOverallHealthStatus.objects.all().values('domain_name').annotate(Max('created')).order_by()
```

This query returning me only id and created.

```
<QuerySet [{'domain_name': 1, 'created__max': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 31, 9, 14, 49, 217073, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}, {'domain_name': 2, 'created__max': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 31, 9, 14, 50, 338368, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}]>
```

But I need to fetch every column of DomainOverallHealthStatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query you wanted:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

o_health = DomainOverallHealthStatus.objects.alias(
    latest=Max('domain_name__overall_health_status_domain_name__created')
).filter(
    created=F('latest')
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved. But I am so sorry that I can't understand the query. Can you make me understand?

Comment: @Samrat for every health status, checks the related domain name and gets highest ```created``` field of its health statuses. Then checks ```created``` value of health status with the founded ```created``` value of previous step, and keeps it if they're equal.

Comment: if you didn't understand what i said, you can test the query and print its sql query